# QGraphicsscene.itemAt() method throws an error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a custom scene that will print the item at mouse position in `qgraphicsscene`.
But, I get an error when I run the code using the cmd.

Here is the full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 10, in mousePressEvent
    print(self.itemAt(event.pos()))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  itemAt(self, Union[QPointF, QPoint], QTransform): not enough arguments
  itemAt(self, float, float, QTransform): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPointF'
```

Here is the code.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Scene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # print(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.mapToScene(event.pos()))
        print(self.itemAt(event.pos()))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    scene = Scene()

    rect1 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(QtCore.QRectF(20, 20, 100, 100))
    rect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(QtCore.QRectF(20, 20, 100, 100))

    # rect1.setFlag(rect1.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
    # rect2.setFlag(rect2.ItemIgnoresTransformations)

    rect1.setFlag(rect1.ItemIsMovable)
    rect2.setFlag(rect2.ItemIsMovable)

    scene.addItem(rect1)
    scene.addItem(rect2)

    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I did refer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824951/pyqt5-questions-about-qgraphicsscenes-itemat-and-focusitemchanged) but couldn't figure out how to properly use this method. Please answer this with a little more explanation.

(Also, note that I did try to use `event.pos().toPoint()` I get a similar error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the traceback says, you're missing the `QTransform` argument, as also shown in the argument signature of [`itemAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#itemAt):

> `itemAt(const QPointF &position, const QTransform &deviceTransform)`

As you can see, they are both positional arguments, there's no keyworded/default argument.

So, assuming you're not using any transformation, you have to add at least a new `QTransform()` instance. Do note that in case of `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`, the `pos()` is in item coordinates, and since the event is called on the scene and not on an item, you need to use is the `scenePos()` instead.

Keep also in mind that in order to correctly allow item movement as per the `ItemIsMovable` flag you used, you must also call the default base implementation.

```
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QtGui.QTransform()))
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
```